# EventServiceProvider mapping for Laravel 5.2 login

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to update user's `last_login_at` when a user login on Laravel 5.2. I used `php artisan make:auth`.

I have app/Listeners/UpdateLastLoginOnLogin.php.

```
namespace App\Listeners;

use Carbon\Carbon;

class UpdateLastLoginOnLogin
{
    public function handle($user, $remember)
    {
        $user->last_login_at = Carbon::now();

        $user->save();
    }
}
```

And in app/Providers/EventServiceProvider:

namespace App\Providers;

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher as DispatcherContract;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        'auth.login' => [
            'App\Listeners\UpdateLastLoginOnLogin',
        ],
    ];
    /**
     * Register any other events for your application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher  $events
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
    { 
      ...
```

I have the followings in app/User.php

```
protected $dates = ['last_login_at'];
```

And in my app/Http/Controllers/Admin/DashboardController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Blog;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Blog $blogs, User $users)
    {
        $blogs = $blogs->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->take(5)->get();

        $users = $users->whereNotNull('last_login_at')->orderBy('last_login_at', 'desc')->take(5)->get();

        return view('admin.dashboard', compact('blogs','users'));
    }
}
```

It was working in Laravel 5.1 but it doesn't in Laravel 5.2.8. I think the problem is mapping in EventServiceProvider, `'auth.login' => ['App\Listeners\UpdateLastLoginOnLogin',]`. I tried `login` and `Auth::login()` instead of `auth.login` but they didn't work either.

How can I map `protcted $listen`?

Answer (score 2):

Some Events have changed in 5.2 as per the upgrade guide:

> "Some of the core events fired by Laravel now use event objects instead of string event names and dynamic parameters." - Laravel 5.2 Upgrade Guide

```
OLD              NEW
auth.attempting  Illuminate\Auth\Events\Attempting
auth.login       Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login
auth.logout      Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout
```

[Laravel Docs - 5.2 Upgrade Guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0)

The handle method will now be taking the event as its argument

```
...
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login;

class UpdateLastLoginOnLogin
{
    public function handle(Login $event)
    {
        $event->user->last_login_at = Carbon::now();
        $event->user->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error of FatalErrorException in UpdateLastLoginOnLogin.php line 14: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login::save()

Comment: you are calling save on the event? perhaps you mean to do that on the model?

Comment: Well, I just want to update user's last_login_at when a user logged in.