# Laravel 5.2 Login Event Handling

Tags: php, laravel, events, authentication, laravel-5

In the database I have a table users with column last_login_at. Everytime when some user logs in - I want to uptade *last_login_at*.

So, I created app/Listeners/**UpdateLastLoginOnLogin.php**:

```
namespace App\Listeners;

use Carbon\Carbon;

class UpdateLastLoginOnLogin
{
    public function handle($user, $remember)
    {
        $user->last_login_at = Carbon::now();

        $user->save();
    }
}
```

In app/Providers/EventServiceProvider:

```
    protected $listen = [
        'auth.login' => [
            'App\Listeners\UpdateLastLoginOnLogin',
        ],
    ];
```

BUT this doesn't work, event is not handled. The same problem has already been mentioned here: [EventServiceProvider mapping for Laravel 5.2 login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34974192/eventserviceprovider-mapping-for-laravel-5-2-login) but without solution. I have tried to do like this:

...

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login;

class UpdateLastLoginOnLogin
{
    public function handle(Login $event)
    {
        $event->user->last_login_at = Carbon::now();
        $event->user->save();
    }
}
```

and:

```
protected $listen = [
    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => [
        'App\Listeners\UpdateLastLoginOnLogin',
    ],
];
```

But it doesn't work.

Also, I checked this: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/login-event-handling-in-laravel-5 but **php artiasn clear-compiled** didn't solve the problem.

**EDIT:** FOR OTHER DETAILS, HERE'S A LINK TO THE PROJECT which is actually exactly the same (it is done in the same way): https://github.com/tutsplus/build-a-cms-with-laravel

Comment: How do you log your users in?

Comment: @noodles_ftw Here's a link to the project which is actually exactly the same (it is done in the same way): https://github.com/tutsplus/build-a-cms-with-laravel

Comment: Have you fired it by yourself from anywhere?

Comment: @The Alpha Yes, and nothing happens - _last_login_at_ is not updated, no errors. I am using Laravel 5.2 (latest version), but the code I pasted here was used on 5.1 and it worked there. This question was already asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34974192/eventserviceprovider-mapping-for-laravel-5-2-login, but there is no answer that solves this problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are almost there, just a few changes more, Events and Listeners for authentication have changed a little in Laravel 5.2:
the handle method in **UpdateLastLoginOnLogin** should have just an event as parameter

```
namespace App\Listeners;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Auth;

class UpdateLastLoginOnLogin
{
    public function handle($event)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->last_login_at = Carbon::now();
        $user->save();
    }
}
```

And for the **EventServiceProvider** you specify the listeners like this :

```
protected $listen = [
    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => [
        'App\Listeners\UpdateLastLoginOnLogin@handle',
    ],
];
```

Comment: I have a question suppose, we have multiple events to Listen, then should we write every time different listener in EventServiceProvider?

Comment: if the events are independant, logically you need a listener for every event. as you'v seen below, a listener can be in another class, so you just activate it in the EventServiceProvider on a specified event