# Laravel 5.3 Remember me Auth issue

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.3

I have implemented a remember me login in my laravel 5.3 project, but iam running with some issues, when the user return to the page its automaticaly logged in but the custom sessions variables are not set because the session already expired.

I have my sessions lifetime to 120 and expire on close is true.

My question is: how do I check if the user is being authed via remember me token to reasign session variables? I was thinking to create a Middleware for that but i don't know if thats the correct approach.

My customs sessions variables are:

```
session()->get('client_id') -> int
session()->get('acl') -> array
```

Can anyone guide me to the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the following solution and see if it works.

[Determine if the User Was Authenticated Via the Remember Cookie](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/83/determine-if-the-user-was-authenticated-via-the-remember-cookie)

Edited:

Add a event Listener to `EventServiceProvider`

```
 protected $listen = [
        'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => [
            'App\Listeners\UpdateLoginType@handle',
        ],
    ];
```

Generate event and handler for the listener

```
php artisan event:generate
```

Go To `UpdateLoginType` and edit `handle` method to check login type

```
 public function handle(Login $event)
    {
        if (\Auth::viaRemember()) {
            //do something
        } else {
            //do something else
        }
    }
```

Make sure your pass the `remember` variable properly while logging in.

Question similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35295062/laravel-5-2-login-event-handling)

Comment: I know the function viaRemember() but it always returns false no matter what i do its always false, but my question is where to use this ?

Comment: @Galfau answer edited. can you try and see if it works.

Comment: it worked perfectly, as a Event i just moved the session()-set() logic from AuthController@login to the Event and now i dont need to use the Auth::viaRemember() since Laravel will always throw  that event upon login successful. Thanks!

Comment: by the way the method viaRemember() returns true only if the users is returning to the page and using the remember_me_token cookie to authenticate, not when the user checks the remember me box on the login page, I've seen a lot of people saying that it always returns false and it is because of that.